# How to get current day,month and year from Extended Calendar View android and adding events to a particular date

Tags: android, calendarview

I have implemented extended calendar view(com.tyczj.extendedcalendarview.ExtendedCalendarView) in my project.But i was unable to get current date from extended calendar view.I would like to get the day,month and year from calendar and display it in another 3 textviews. I would like to add events to some particular dates and changing the background color of that particular day.Please help me to find a solution for this

Answer (score 1):

This should work for a calendar:

```
final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
```